# C++: Deque Iterator Not Dereferenceable; can't find the rogue pop/top

Tags: c++, stack, deque

I'm doing something very similar to what this user did:
[Error: deque iterator not dereferenceable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977349/error-deque-iterator-not-dereferenceable)

I've been looking for an age but I just cannot see where I'm going wrong. The solution to the other poster was finding a place where he tried to pop or top from a deque with zero elements. I can't find where I'm doing that in my code.

EDIT: I suspect the issue is within SYAlg or OSProcess, if that helps.

```
// TestCalculator.cpp : main project file.

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;
//using std::string;

bool lastCharDigit = true;
string RawString; //Contains the raw equation the user types in.

deque<string> TokenEquation(1); //Contains the equation in tokenised infix form.
deque<string> RPNEquation; //Contains the equation in tokenised RPN form.
deque<string> OperatorStack; //Used as part of the Shunting Yard Algorithm
deque<string> SolverStack; //Used to solve the RPN Equation.

locale loc; //Used to verify digits.
//START FUNCTION DECLARATION
int main();
void tokeniser(string RawEquation);
void SYAlg();
void OSProcess(string newOperator);
void Solver();
//END FUNCTION DECLARATION


int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid infix notation equation, without parenthesis.\n";
    cin >> RawString;
    tokeniser(RawString);
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void tokeniser(string RawEquation)
{
    int testCharPos = -1; // Initialise the index of the raw string
    int tokenVectorPos = 0; // Initialise the token array position
    int tokenVectorPrintPos = 0; // Initialise the print position

    for (int eLength = RawEquation.length(); eLength != 0; eLength--) // For each character in the Raw string...
    {
        testCharPos++; // Increment the char we're testing
        char testChar = RawEquation.at(testCharPos); // Establish the current test char

        if (isdigit(testChar, loc)) //If the testchar is a digit
        {
            if (lastCharDigit) //If the last character was a digit
            {
                TokenEquation[tokenVectorPos] += testChar; //Append the tested char to the current token array pos
            }
            if (!lastCharDigit) //If the last character was not a digit
            {
                TokenEquation.push_back(string(1, testChar)); //Establish a new element with the testchar in it.
                tokenVectorPos++;
            }
            lastCharDigit = true;
        }

        if (!isdigit(testChar, loc))//If the testchar is not a digit
        {
            TokenEquation.push_back(string(1, testChar)); //Establish a new element with the testchar in it.
            tokenVectorPos++;
            lastCharDigit = false;
        }
    }

    cout << "The tokens of that equation are:\n\n"; //Outputs the tokens for testing purposes.

    for (int tokenLength = TokenEquation.size(); tokenLength != 0; tokenLength--)
    {
        cout << "     " << TokenEquation[tokenVectorPrintPos];
        cout << "\n";
        tokenVectorPrintPos++;
    }

    SYAlg(); //Call the SYAlg.
}

void SYAlg() //This function uses Shunting Yard Algorithm to convert the Infix tokens to RPN.
{
    cout << TokenEquation.size();
    for (int testtokenLength = TokenEquation.size(); testtokenLength != 0; testtokenLength--) //For each token in the tokenised deque
    {
        if (isdigit(TokenEquation.front().at(0), loc)) //Check if it's a number
        {
            RPNEquation.push_back(TokenEquation.front()); //Add the first raw token to the RPN Equation
            TokenEquation.pop_front(); //Pop the token from the deque
        }
        if (!isdigit(TokenEquation.front().at(0), loc)) //If it's an operator
        {
            OSProcess(TokenEquation.front()); //Run the SYAlg operator stack procedure. NB This will pop the front of the TokenEquation for you.
        }
    }


    cout << "The tokens of that equation are:\n\n"; //Outputs the tokens for testing purposes.
    int RPNPrintPos = 0;
    for (int tokenLength = RPNEquation.size(); tokenLength != 0; tokenLength--)
    {
        cout << "     " << RPNEquation[RPNPrintPos];
        cout << "\n";
        RPNPrintPos++;
    }
}

void OSProcess(string newOperator) //This function processes the Operator Stack
{
    bool PushedNewOperator = false;
    std::string newOpSTD = newOperator; //Creates an std::string version of the argument for easier comparison.
    while (PushedNewOperator == false){ //As long as the new operator is still waiting to go to the stack
        if (!OperatorStack.empty()) //If there's already an operator on the stack
        {
            if (newOpSTD == "/" || "*")
            {
                std::string OSBackSTD = OperatorStack.back(); //Create an STD version of the back of the OpStack for comparison.
                if (OSBackSTD == "+" || "-")
                {
                    OperatorStack.push_back(newOperator); //Add the tested operator to the stack
                    TokenEquation.pop_front(); //And pop it from the token equation
                    PushedNewOperator = true; //Set the flag variable to true so we stop looping
                }
                else
                {
                    RPNEquation.push_back(OperatorStack.back()); //Add the top of the operator stack to the equation
                    OperatorStack.pop_back(); //Pop this back
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RPNEquation.push_back(OperatorStack.back()); //Add the top of the operator stack to the equation
                OperatorStack.pop_back(); //Pop this back
            }
        }
        if (OperatorStack.empty())
        {
            OperatorStack.push_back(newOperator); //Add the tested operator to the stack
            TokenEquation.pop_front(); //And pop it from the token equation
            PushedNewOperator = true; //Set the flag variable to true so we stop looping
        }
    }
    //For each operator on the stack, until the following statement returns false...
    //Check if the precedence of newOperator is less than or equal to the top operator.
}

void Solver() //This function solves the RPNEquation
{
    //Push each token to the solver stack
    //If you push an operator, solve it against the stack
    //When the RPN equation is empty and the solver stack only has one token in it, you have a solution
}
```

Comment: Know when to use a debugger and when to post a new question.

Comment: I've never actually used breakpoints before and I'm struggling to understand them. I did some research on them and had a play around in the IDE (Visual Studio 2013) but I'm not confident with them. Could you offer me some advice?

Comment: @Mort432, I'd recommend you to use  some `printf` or `std::cout` to debug and some `abort()` calls when you in doubt whether some code runs at all. I think debugger in most cases is overpower. Debugger is great when something goes wrong totally and you have general protection fault or core dump, then you can see backtrace stack easy.

Comment: A breakpoint does what it says: it stops the program's execution at the point where you set the breakpoint. Once it stops, you can execute one line at a time, and you can usually look into the local variables and such so you can watch *exactly* what happens.

Comment: @2807083 Many thanks, was thinking of doing that.

2475059 I sort of understand what happens, just still working out how to implement and use it for my benefit

Comment: Change `if (newOpSTD == "/" || "*")` to `if (newOpSTD.compare("/") == 0 || newOpSTD.compare("*") == 0)` ... unless what you meant to write was `if (true)`.

Comment: Submit that an an answer and I'll hug your soul.

Comment: Hold on, I just did this and it's still throwing out the same error. Will have a tinker and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major issue is with the multitude of lines which say `if (newOpSTD == "/" || "*")`, or something to that effect. These need to be changed to `if (newOpSTD.compare("/") == 0 || newOpSTD.compare("*") == 0)`.

I think these checks failing means the `while` loop they're in turns into `while(true)`.

Comment: I have figured out the source of the issue now. I'll pick this answer as it very much put my mind on the right track. Many thanks.

Comment: I put it in my own environment and had issues with it double-popping in `SYAlg()`. I'm assuming that's what you found?

Comment: Absolutely! While the double popping is a little rough around the edges, there's no harm in it innately that I can see, so I made the if statements check if the deque was empty before doing anything, which fixed it up. Thanks again! P.S. I understand breakpoints way more now, those were how I figured it out.

Comment: Looking at it one more time, I'd say it might need to be an `if` `else` instead of two `if`s. There's nothing technically wrong with two pops (it's basically unwrapping the loop), it's more that it doesn't make for clean logic, and people reading it later will expect clean logic and not tricks. If you insist on leaving a double pop, leave a comment saying something to the effect of "I meant to double-pop because <reasons>."