# C++ - Nested containers (list container of stack containers)

Tags: c++, list, stl, linked-list, stack

I want to create a linked list of stack objects using STL. This is how my code looks like:

```
int main() {
    stack<int> s1;
    list<stack<int>> ll;
    s1.push(0)
    ll.push_back(s1);
    auto it = ll.begin();
    it++;
    cout << *it->top() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are illegal indirection and '<<' illegal for class on the second last line. What seems to be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on the fourth line, on line 8 it should be it->top(), and you're trying to access past the end of the list.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added the basic code of a much complex version (was actually iterating through the list with multiple stacks in it using a for loop), so forgot to make the change appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your line to read as follows:

```
cout << (*it).top() << endl;
```

You were dereferencing the value instead of a pointer to the value. Notice that I changed the `->` to a `.`
The nuts and bolts are that 'it' is essentially a pointer to your value and '*it' gives you the value so when you want to access members of that value you need a `.` instead of a `->`

Update: Also, as was pointed out by others, there is a missing ; after the push and you've only added one item to the list and then incremented your iterator which positions you at the end of the list, after the one value. This will cause you run time problems.

Comment: and "cout <<  it->top() " is also valid syntax. even though syntax would be correct, second last line will cause segmentation fault, since you are accessing iterator which is outside range.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I did not put that in my answer because that wasn't part of the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: This solution makes perfect sense! I was trying to do *it.top() but (*it).top() definitely makes more sense. About the other errors: sorry about that, I just added the basic code of a much complex version (was actually iterating through the list with multiple stacks in it using a for loop), so forgot to make the change appropriately

Comment: I'm actually still getting a runtime error when I try to iterate the list (containing multiple stacks): deque iterator not dereferencable.

Comment: I wonder if this question might help with that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977349/error-deque-iterator-not-dereferenceable

Comment: I figured out what the problem is: I was creating multiple stack objects initially and pushing elements onto them, but I wasn't really passing the reference to those objects when pushing onto the linked list (which was creating its own empty stack objects in the memory, thus trying to access top() from empty stacks). How would I create a list of stack objects which use references to originally defined stacks? I am using `list<stack<int>> ll` to initialize it. Or how do I not create stack objects initially but within the linked list object, something like `ll.push_back(new stack<int>)`?

Comment: This should probably be a separate question ... There's a few ways to deal with this that I can think of. The most obvious to me is to push onto the stack that is in the list and bypass any external stacks. If for some reason you must have the stacks external then you could go list<stack<int>&>. Or you could create a list of objects that contain a stack and make your list take a reference to that object.